# Pi Camera v2.1: Video recording and video streaming

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, camera

Can video recording and at the same time streaming on a web application be done? Also, how can it be downloaded on the web, considering I have made the web application?

Comment: Sure, [pistreaming](https://github.com/waveform80/pistreaming) is a little demo of MPEG1 streaming, combine that with the [recording multiple resolutions](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes2.html#recording-at-multiple-resolutions) recipes and you can easily record a file at the same time. Tweaking the pistreaming server to serve the resulting file from some URL wouldn't be difficult either.

Comment: @DaveJones  
A code was already made for video recording and for video streaming on a web page. The event of streaming and recording is controlled via switch button on the web page. New problem occurred, Streaming is good but when switched to recording, MMLA error pops. The streaming is still running in the background. Raspi Cam seems could not process two function at a time. BTW here's the code used (blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

Answer (score 1):

[UV4L](https://www.linux-projects.org) can record while streaming audio/video in real time with any browser (plug-in free, including mobiles) from a web page that can be customized according to your needs. The recorded audio-video webm can be stored to disk or played back. It works out-of-the-box. The latency with the latest versions is under <150ms in a LAN, the fastest AFAIK. As UV4L is also a framework you can write your web app with the provided REST API. For further informations read through the documentation.

Comment: A code was already made for video recording and for video streaming on a web page. The event of streaming and recording is controlled via switch button on the web page. New problem occurred, Streaming is good but when switched to recording, MMLA error pops. The streaming is still running in the background. Raspi Cam seems could not process two function at a time. BTW here's the code used (blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)